# Rails get title of associated resource by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 models(Clients and Projects) that are connected like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cliente
end

class Cliente < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
end
```

Projects have a `:cliente_id` column in its schema, so if I do:

`Project.cliente_id` I will get the cliente_id correctly.

My doubt is, I want to get the **client name** from it's id, so I need something like:

```
Project.cliente_id.name
```

Which is the correct way to retrieve this info?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the complete `Cliente` object with `project.cliente` (note that the `_id` is not used). So you can use it like a regular `Cliente`; for example, to get `name` just do:

```
project = Project.find(1)
project.cliente.name
```

Comment: I will get: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass, Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok thanks! I had to check if Cliente was associated first. Worked as a charm!

Comment: This answer confuses the class with the instance. For example, `Project.cliente` is attempting to call a instance method on a class object. This answer is wrong, and it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @anothermh Good catch, i've corrected the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You find associated objects [through the association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

```
project = Project.find(1) # Returns the full `project` object
project.cliente # Returns the full `cliente` object
project.cliente.name # Returns just the `name` attribute
project.cliente_id == project.cliente.id # Returns true
```